# Imputation of Missing Values by Categorical Mean?

Tags: r, statistics, imputation

I have a dataset with several columns, one of which is missing chunks of data that is needed.

The column with missing data, df$Variable, is always attributed to a specific person, df$Name. Is there a way to impute each person's average - rather than the entire dataset's average - whenever there is missing data in df$Variable?

I've been playing around with the imputeTS library.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the data frame in the current form that it is in and also the example of the desired output please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add mean columns to dataframe by category with NA's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932302/add-mean-columns-to-dataframe-by-category-with-nas)

Answer (score 1):

Tough to answer definitively without a reproducible example, but given what you've said, something like this should work:

```
library('tidyverse')

df <- data.frame(Name = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5)),
                 Variable = sample(c(1, 2, 3, NA), 10, replace = TRUE))

df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(non_na_mean = mean(Variable, na.rm = T)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(newVariable = ifelse(is.na(Variable), non_na_mean, Variable))
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data frame, I believe this would work.

```
set.seed(7)
# make some fake data
df <- data.frame(Name = rep(as.character(c("A", "B", "C", "D")), 10), Variable = sample(1:100, 40))
# change some to NA
df[which(df$Variable > 40),"Variable"] <- NA

# Fill in NA's for D with the mean of D
df[which(df$Name == "D" & is.na(df$Variable)),"Variable"] <-
  mean(df[which(df$Name == "D"),"Variable"], na.rm = TRUE)
```

You can also loop through other 'Variables'

```
variable_vec <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
for(i in 1:length(variable_vec)){
df[which(df$Name == i & is.na(df$Variable)),"Variable"] <-
  mean(df[which(df$Name == i),"Variable"], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```